# function is not working after adding class to a button

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql, datatables

**On Click of Button addClass and removeClass when I call function on click using class button is not working**

- am getting php variable to display button in the table
- based on php variable value am displaying buttons
- on click of button want to change that button class and call one more function to display child row

```
<?php
$stageid = $row["Stage_ID"];
?>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
<td>BW101.01</td>
<?php
if($stageid == 1)
{
?>
echo'<td><button type="button" class="clarify">Clarify</button></td>';
<?php }
else
{ ?>
echo'<td><button type="button" class="allot">Allot</button></td>';
<?php } ?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now am calling function and sending button value to backend and update on ajax success I want to call the child row table

```
 $(".clarify").click(function(e) {
        $this = $(this);
        var drawingid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id'); // table row ID 
        var stage_id = $(this).closest('tr').find('.clarify').val();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "stage2.php",
          dataType: "json",
          data: {
            "drawingID": drawingid,
            "stage_ID": stage_id
          },
          success: function(data) {
            $this.parent().parent().find('.clarify').html('Allott').addClass('allot').removeClass('clarify');
          }
        });
      });
```

now  am calling a function on click of the second button I want to display the child row table

```
 $(function() {
          $('.allot').on('click', function(e) {

            // to avoid to receive the button click inside the td you need:

            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            id = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
            table = $('#' + id).DataTable();
            var row = table.row(tr);
            if (row.child.isShown()) {
              // This row is already open - close it
              row.child.hide();
              tr.removeClass('shown');
            } else {
              // Open this row
              row.child(format(row.data(), id)).show();
              tr.addClass('shown');
            }
          });
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#example').DataTable();

        });

        function format(d, id) {
          //`d` is the original data object for the row
          //if(sessionStorage['name']!=undefined)
          return '<table id="error"style="width:100%">' +
            '<tr>' +
            '<th>Drawing:</th>' +
            '<th>Designer</th>' +
            '<th>Time</th>' +
            '<th><button type="button">Start</button></th>' +
            '</tr>' +
            '<tr>' +
            '<td></td>' +
            '<td></td>' +
            '<td>00:00</td>' +
            '<td></td>' +
            '</tr>' +
            '</table>';
        }
```

Comment: in the first code block ,you forget to put <?php  before if

Comment: Yup Now its changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

am just adding  click button class name inside table tbody function Now it is working :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable();

        $('#example tbody').on('click', '.allot', function() {
          var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();
         // alert(data[0] + "'s salary is: " + data[5]);
          var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
          $this.parent().parent().find('div.progress .progress-bar').css("width", "20%").text(2);
          id = $(this).closest('table').attr('id');
          table = $('#' + id).DataTable();
          var row = table.row(tr);
          if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
          } else {
            // Open this row
            row.child(format(row.data(), id)).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
          }
        });
      });
```